# Using "can't help" construction

Tags: gerunds

Is "can't help" used correctly? If not, what should be changed?

> Even in the darkened room I couldn't help seeing Mrs. Jones's face swollen with tears.

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  You can also say "I couldn't help but see ..."

Comment: It's fine grammatically, but in order to know whether you've used it correctly, we need to know what you hope to say using it. I suspect that what you mean and what this sentence means are the same, but just to be sure, can you paraphrase the sentence? (P.S. your sentence should read "Mrs. Jones' face".)

Comment: "Can't help" isn't contained within your sentence.. "couldn't help" is, but not the former. Please specify which you're concerned about.